# How to move blog to a custom path in drupal?

Tags: routes, nodes

I want to move default blogs to a custom URL
i.e. blog are by default present at ./blog  but i want them to be at ./share/blog I don't want to use path aliases. I want a permanent move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a 'permanent' move you'll need to write a custom module and implement `hook_menu_alter()`, to copy the settings for the original path over to the new one, and remove the old page from the system:

```
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  if (isset($items['blog'])) {
    $items['share/blog'] = $items['blog'];
    unset($items['blog'];
  }
}
```

That will just do the core 'blog' page, the blog module defines 4 paths (see [`blog_menu()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21blog%21blog.module/function/blog_menu/7)), each of which you'll need to override if you want make this change fully. You might also need to do some further digging into the code the blog module produces as I'm not sure if any of those paths are hard-coded into URLs or anything like that.